# firestore sync time between clients

Tags: javascript, reactjs, time, google-cloud-firestore, momentjs

I have this document structure in firestore collection

```
{ message: 'hello world', time: 1538398128 }
```

time value is set by client when it posts message with this function

```
moment().unix()
```

The problem is that my clients have different time and if I sort documents by time it is inconsistent, like this example

```
{ message: 'aaa', time: 1538398317 } // client 1 post at 14.00:00
{ message: 'bbb', time: 1538398257 } // client 2 post at 14:00:10
```

and on client I see "bbb" before "aaa".
How can I fix this problem?
I know that exists firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(), but it gives me the value only after I posted the document, i can't use this on client.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well you will need to pick one timezone and use it as standard for a consistent data storage, otherwise every client will use the local one. You might want to use `moment-timezone` an extension for momentjs where you can specify the timezone you want to use : https://momentjs.com/timezone/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already use moment.tz.setDefault('Europe/London'), but the difference between clients is about 30 seconds

Comment: If 2 users perfom an action "at the same time" (keep in mind that is kinda impossible that 2 clients deliver the same Date.now value)  they still have a difference of 30 secs?

Comment: Because moment().unix() get client time, and my computer displays 15:30:00 and my colleague 15:29:15 (clients are not sync with NTP server)

Comment: same problem, because clients have different time...moment uses local client date/time

Comment: Formatting the same unix timestamp should return the same value if you specify the timezone. This : `moment.unix(1318781876).tz('Europe/London').format()` should return exactly the same date in 2 different clients... js and timezones, damn xD..

Comment: yes, but if clients are on the same place, like office, using timezones doesn't fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to perfectly sync different client devices (phones/browsers) with time, as you have no mechanism to force their clocks to be in sync.

To ensure a consistent ordering, you will need to use `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`, which once committed will be returned to the client. While you are waiting for it, you can use the client time as a fallback mechanism. Even better, you can reach out to some time server to validate that the local clock hasn't drifted too far from being usable.